# Start developing with MVC4 Web Api today, using Beta?

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am struggeling...

Is it safe to start developing with MVC4 Web Api (BETA) in a project that will be released live 2012 Q2.
I have heard that final version of MVC4 will be released 2012 Q3.
Since I really believe in MVC4 Web API and its capabilities, using some other technique will feel bad and will make the project look old fast.
I also think, building REST services with WCF is a step in the wrong direction since it was not designed for that.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to start using MVC 4 Beta Web API. It has a go live license which means you can deploy it to a live server (though keep in mind that it is Beta software subject to change).

We are not commenting right now on exact release schedules and that Q3 quote does not sound reliable at all.

Comment: I hope it doesn't change as much as it did from preview 6 :)

Comment: Not as much. But we know already that some of the APIs will change: remove `HttpResponseMessage<T>`/`HttpRequestMessage<T>`, make `ObjectContent<T>` constructor public, details of how content negotiation is performed, JSON serialization will be more flexible, model-binding and validation details. Probably a few more as well.

Comment: Hmm I can live with methods changing and new methods added. Model-binding sounds to me like a bigger issue, feels like this may affect my code a lot, when updating from Beta.

Comment: @marcind Earlier, WCF Web API was developed out in the open which was kind of nice to follow. Do you plan on doing the same so that we can adopt the changes in an easier way?

Comment: We have now decided to do the REST api with WCF. Feels to unstable to relese a product to a customer based on Beta.

Comment: @tugberk we're working on opening up some mroe communication channels, but nothing to announce at this time

Comment: @Flatron that's probably a good call if you need to ship soon. Web API will have changes before RTM.